# How to draw in C++ with Cairo to a window using GDI (instead of creating an image)?

Tags: c++, c, cairo

I managed to find this code snippet and compile it with Cairo:

```
#define LIBCAIRO_EXPORTS
#include <cairo/cairo.h>
#include <cairo/cairo-win32.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cairo_surface_t *surface;
    cairo_t *cr;
    surface = cairo_image_surface_create (CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, 240, 80);
    cr = cairo_create (surface);

    cairo_select_font_face (cr, "serif", CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL,
                                         CAIRO_FONT_WEIGHT_BOLD);
    cairo_set_font_size (cr, 32.0);
    cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    cairo_move_to (cr, 10.0, 50.0);
    cairo_show_text (cr, "Hello, World");
    cairo_destroy (cr);
    cairo_surface_write_to_png (surface, "hello.png");
    cairo_surface_destroy (surface);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, it create an image with the text "Hello World" and saved it on the drive.
How do I go about creating a win32 surface and draw to a window instead?

I am failing to use: `cairo_win32_surface_create`

It requires a `hdc` and I don't know what that is. I tried to read a few tutorials but none seems to walk you through printing to a new window.

I found this link:
http://windrealm.org/cairo-gdi/

It has a working demo but it uses `int WINAPI WinMain`. I don't wish to use that.

Comment: An `HDC` is a handle to a device context, which is basically a virtual canvas with state including a selected pen, selected brush, and selected bitmap. I hope that helps at least a little bit.

Comment: If you are not familiar with Windows GDI development you might want to take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145203(v=vs.85).aspx). You'll probably be most interested in [Device Contexts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183553(v=vs.85).aspx) and [Bitmaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183377(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I found this link showing how to use everything except win32 gdi:
http://zetcode.com/gfx/cairo/cairobackends/

Comment: I also found this which seems to answer my question partially:
http://windrealm.org/cairo-gdi/ but it uses winmain which I wish to avoid. Is it even possible?

Comment: You can create a window from a console program, but you'll have to run a message loop to operate it properly. It's easier to start with an example that uses winmain.

Comment: I worked with Allegro before. Could I somehow draw from Cairo to a windows created wit Allegro perhaps?

Answer (score 7):

There are several ways to get a handle to a device context in Windows. For instance it is typical that the `WM_PAINT` handler will call `BeginPaint` to acquire a device context, update the contents to the window and then call `EndPaint`. In cases where `BeginPaint` and `EndPaint` cannot be used (e.g. outside of a WM_PAINT message) you can use `GetDC` update the window and then call `ReleaseDC`.

The device contexts returned by `BeginPaint` and `GetDC` allow you to draw directly to a window. Sometimes however you want to draw directly to a bitmap. In this case you would call `CreateCompatibleDC`, select the bitmap you want to draw to, do your drawing and then call `DeleteDC`.

In your case what you're looking for is something like the following:

```
HDC dc = GetDC(windowHandle);
cairo_win32_surface_create(dc);
ReleaseDC(windowHandle, dc);
```

If you do not want to create a window at this stage (since you are simply saving an image) you can probably get away with using the desktop window to acquire a device context.

```
HWND windowHandle = GetDesktopWindow();
HDC dc = GetDC(windowHandle);
cairo_win32_surface_create(dc);
ReleaseDC(windowHandle, dc);
```

There are other calls that can be used to acquire or create a device context. You can find a list of these and related functions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183554%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Creating and using a window is a bit more involved so I'm going to provide you with the basic steps and some sample code that you can use to play around with. To create and use a window...

- Register a window class with `RegisterClass`
- Create the window with `CreateWindow` or `CreateWindowEx`
- Process messages with a message pump by calling `GetMessage`, `TranslateMessage` and `DispatchMessage`

Additionally you will have to implement a function to handle processing of window messages such as `WM_PAINT`.

**NOTE: The following code is UNTESTED but should be correct.**

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if(message == WM_PAINT)
    {
        HDC dc;
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        dc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        // do your drawing here

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    }

    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    static TCHAR szClassName[] = TEXT("DrawSurfaceClass");
    HWND         hwnd;
    MSG          msg;
    WNDCLASS     wndclass;

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  Register a window "class"
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    wndclass.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wndclass.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground =(HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wndclass.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = szClassName;

    if(!RegisterClass(&wndclass))
    {
        //  error
        return 1;
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  Create the window and display it (if iCmdShow says so)
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    hwnd = CreateWindow(
        szAppName,
        TEXT("Draw Surface"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);


    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  Run the message pump so the window proc recieves events
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: +1, but painting outside of WM_PAINT is generally a bad idea.

Comment: If you look at the question closely you'll see it's a console program with no message loop. `WM_PAINT` is correct but the full answer is way more complicated than that.

Comment: What is a windowHandle? I have seen 'hwnd' mentioned a ton of times. How do I get one?

Comment: @MarkRansom A console application does not preclude you from having a message pump or prevent you from creating windows. I'm editing it to include the window creating and message loop.

Answer (score 2):

I found the easiest way for beginners to open a window and draw some lines into it, is downloading and setting up the gtk+ and using ZetCode's tutorials.

You will probably need to download GTK from here:
http://gtk.hexchat.org/

Setting up Gtk+:
[Using GTK+ in Visual C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513214/using-gtk-in-visual-c)

Cairo tutorials:
http://zetcode.com/gfx/cairo/

Remember to include all the GTK's dll files in the directory where your compiled executable is.